# sorting in file and out C++

Tags: c++

I have the C++ code. It reading file and look for anagrams in this file ("diction").

```
while (1)
{
    infile.getline(buff, sizeof(buff));
    if(infile.eof()) break;
    sbuff = buff;
    sort(sbuff.begin(), sbuff.end());
    an.insert(pair<string, string>(sbuff, buff));
}

im = an.begin();
ane = an.end();

vector<multimap<string, string>::iterator> chg;

chg.push_back(im);

while (++im != ane)
{
    chg.push_back(im);
    if((*im).first != (*chg[0]).first)
    {
        if(chg.size() > 2)
        {
            for(unsigned int i=0; i < chg.size() - 1; i++);
        cout << endl;
        }

        chg.clear();
        chg.push_back(im);
    }   

}

if(chg.size() > 1)
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < chg.size(); i++)
        cout << (*chg[i]).second << endl;
    infile.close();
}
```

After compiling it displays a brunch of empty rows and all.
On MacOS on Fedora the same result

What's amiss?

Comment: Code comments are "amiss"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for loop doesn't do anything in your code:

```
 {
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < chg.size() - 1; i++);
    cout << endl;
 }
```

you don't want the `;` at the end of it, probably. If you take it away it'll just give you lots of empty lines though as you don't `cout` any text to the screen.

Comment: thank you very much!!!

Thank you very much! I delete ; at the end.
And added this line after that:
`cout << (*chg[i]).second << endl;`

It's working!

Answer (score 1):

i thing you miss the `{`

try this

```
if(chg.size() > 1)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < chg.size(); i++)
    { 
        cout << (*chg[i]).second << endl;
     }
    infile.close();
}
```

instead of

```
if(chg.size() > 1)
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < chg.size(); i++)
        cout << (*chg[i]).second << endl;
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank's! In this case the braces no necessary. But it's working though as i don't `{}`. Although they improve code readability.